# Android Lollipop not showing android:background image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I have designed screen where I have used JPEG image as layout background. The complete UI screen is visible correctly in Android 8(**GingerBread**) to Android 19(**Kitkat**). The layout background is not visible in Android 20+(**Lollipop**)

**I am using App Compatibility Library**.

See the screenshot below

**Emulator Android 8**

[image: screenshot of emulator android 8]

---

**Device Kitkat**

[image: kitkat screenshot]

---

**Device Lollipop**

[image: lollipop screenshot]

---

**Solutions already tried**

1. Create another folder **mipmap** and copied the same image there and try to access it using `@mipmap\image_background`. **Nothing changed**.

Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/mainBody"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<!-- android:background="@drawable/login_bg"  -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/vwStruts"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tblLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tbrUserId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtUserId"
                style="@style/EditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:hint="@string/hintEmpId" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tbrPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                style="@style/EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/hintPassword"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tbrLoginAndClear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                style="@style/LoginButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/login" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tblLogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tblLoginMargin"
        android:src="@raw/footer_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**styles.xml, there is NO folder for values-v21**

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**login button drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- On Pressed state -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/btn_login_on_press" />         
        </shape>

     </item>

    <!-- enabled true Not pressed, normal state -->
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="true">
         <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/btn_login_normal" />           
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

**EDIT 1 : Added Styles.xml and button drawables**
**EDIT 2 : Mention usage of support library**

Comment: Post your themes.xml or styles.xml from values folder and other values-v21 aswell.

Comment: your above code is perfect , I have checked same things in android L device and M emulator , may be you have faced style related issue . please share your style.xml which you have used for button as well as main style

Comment: @Shishram check now. I have added both styles. xml

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia added button drawables too

Comment: @AkhilJain, try adding styles. for v21 aswell an test. if you want I can Post an answer which will contain styles for below and above 21 API levels. doing this may solve your problem.

Comment: @Shishram what theme style to provide for v21?? the base theme for app

Comment: @AkhilJain, I have Provided an answer as a reference, modify it according to your requirement!

Comment: Did you place your background image in all of DPIs folder? like drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi.

Comment: I placed in drawable default directory so all DPI will fall on that folder

Comment: set the image on the window and see

Comment: May i know resolution of background image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long time of test and trial, I finally realized..there is nothing wrong with the code or xml or styling or theme settings.

The little needle in the stack of issue was "Prevent bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture android"

Reason, when rendering image on Screen `OpenGLRenderer` ***was not loading bitmap for high resolution*** devices and hence no image was coming on nexus devices.

The work around I used was to manually resize the bitmap progrmatically in `onCreate()` method and set as background for the layout.

Hope it helps for anyone who is not able to load background.

**Feel free to query for more!!**

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're applying your drawable using style, you probably forgot to edit additional style in v21 folder if it exists.

Comment: I have also tried to remove the style and apply directly `android:background` still same result

Answer (score 3):

Use this theme for your activity in `manifest.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    </style>
```

and for above API 21 use this create folder in `res/values-v21` and use this below theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I tried it, I just used `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and nothing Changed. Yes, I am using AppTheme in manifest

Comment: Ok !, because I have used your layout and it works for me in API level above or below 21. so its difficult to tell you without looking into your codebase whats causing your issue...

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of mipmap folder is to give android launcher ability to choose different resolution. So put your image back into drawable folder. the better place to put your image within your background is do like [this](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd). The main idea is to set your background layer as window resource for login activity.

Comment: i used `android:windowBackground` didn't helped that much

Comment: @AkhilJain no one experienc same problem, so the reason is in your code, windowBackground gives you better UX - no white screen while activity loading... In new AndroidStudio I saw some warnings about image resources, MAYBE you need to convert your JPEG to PNG, who knows...

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for this in addition to programmatically resizing the bitmap is just to resize the bitmap externally and place it in a v21 res folder and set it to the background of your view. If there is no prefernce as to how the image should look like accross devices, then just putting it back into the general drawable folder should still work.
Manually resizing the bitmap at runtime might be costly unless you randomly change the background image.