# some android icons not visible in app

Tags: android, xml

hi guys i am having a bit of a hard time i have an android application that uses image buttons in the display so far i have been testing on the same device however when i install it on certain devices some of my icons are not visible doe it still occupies the same space and if you click on where they are suppose to be they still trigger their intended actions i am using png images in the recommended dimensions/densities saved in the drawable folders

36x36 for low-density (LDPI)
48x48 for medium-density (MDPI)
72x72 for high-density (HDPI)
96x96 for extra high-density (XHDPI)
180x180 for extra extra high-density (XXHDPI)
192x192 for extra extra extra high-density (XXXHDPI)

plese let me know how to resulv this

Comment: can you post the screenshot where icons are showed and where not

Answer (score 0):

use low dimension images

Reason, when rendering image on Screen OpenGLRenderer was not loading bitmap for high resolution devices and hence no image was coming on nexus devices.

please refer :- [Android Lollipop not showing android:background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481291/android-lollipop-not-showing-androidbackground-image)

please let me know if it is dose not work for you.

Comment: @user2692997 already mentioned that he is using proper densities images then how can be it possible the bitmaps are toolarge